# I can't make calls to the rest/all/V1/subscribers endpoint

Tags: api, newsletter-subscriber

I am trying to get the subscribers of the newsletter who are not customers, they are not in the customers table but in the subscribers module.

I have found this documentation:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4376907/TVsxCSUj

But when trying to perform a GET with API, it does not recognize the route or apply searchcriteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Magento_Newsletter module has no endpoints by default, those endpoints are from a custom module.

Comment: Is there a simple module that can be installed to be able to collect this information through the API? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEstevez I have quickly created this Newsletter Endpoint module and you can access the source code here: https://github.com/reshadzazai/M2-Newsletter-Endpoint/tree/main/NewsletterEndpoint 
You can further improve it as I have created it in a limited time. I have tested the two endpoints and it works fine.